# Check Http & Https Url Exists in c sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Currently Working on a project which i am facing a problem to check the HTTPS URL is correct or not. Now i have done validation for HTTP in c# now i want validation for HTTPS

My code for HTTP Validation.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

// execute the request
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Response.Clear();
Response.Write(response.StatusDescription);
Response.End();
```

Anil

Comment: for HTTPS validation I think the code should work... have you tried passing an URL with Https instead of HTTP?

Comment: yes but i am getting Bad gateway response .

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: try settings the credential ... myProxy.Credentials=new NetworkCredential(username,password);

Comment: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN

> The Create method returns a descendant of the WebRequest class
> determined at run time as the closest registered match for requestUri.
>
> **For example, when a URI beginning with http:// or https:// is passed
> in requestUri, an HttpWebRequest is returned by Create**.
>
> If a URI beginning with ftp:// is passed instead, the Create method will return
> a FileWebRequest instance. If a URI beginning with file:// is passed
> instead, the Create method will return a FileWebRequest instance.
>
> The pre-registered reserve types already registered include the
> following:
>
> http://
>
> https://
>
> ftp://
>
> file://
>
> The .NET Framework includes support for the http://, https://, ftp://,
> and file:// URI schemes. Custom WebRequest descendants to handle other
> requests are registered with the RegisterPrefix method.

Full reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx)

To resolve the error: *"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"* write this code before the request and the certificate should validate.

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    delegate(
        object sender,
        X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
             return true;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref : http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/166/page2.html

```
try
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.httprecipes.com/1/5/https.php");

    WebRequest http = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
}
    catch(UriFormatException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid URL");
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to URL");
}
```